# Problem with Camera.startPreview()

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm following [this tutorial](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK%3a-Part-1) to learn Android's Camera API. I made it the end of the first section (right before "Providing an overlay" begins), and I'm getting the following error:

```
06-20 23:33:50.903: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
06-20 23:33:50.903: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.sobel.Sobel.startCamera(Sobel.java:73)
06-20 23:33:50.903: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.sobel.Sobel.surfaceChanged(Sobel.java:36)
```

([Full trace](http://pastie.org/2099526))

Git repo [here](https://github.com/adelevie/Sobel/). Main Activity [here](https://github.com/adelevie/Sobel/blob/master/src/com/sobel/Sobel.java). Manifest [here](https://github.com/adelevie/Sobel/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

I checked and re-checked my code and have followed the tutorial to a t, so what could be causing this error?

Comment: That part of the log is not significant... can you paste a little more (things above of what you already pasted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the type of Surface in initCamera().

```
private void initCamera() {
mCamSV = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
mCamSH = mCamSV.getHolder();
mCamSH.addCallback(this);
**mCamSH.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);**

}
```

**EDIT 1**

I am copying all the files here which worked for me with android 2.2 sdk

**Activity**

```
package com.stack.camera;


import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraStackActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Camera mCam;
    private SurfaceView mCamSV;
    private SurfaceHolder mCamSH;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initCamera();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopCamera();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    startCamera(holder, width, height);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCam = Camera.open();
    try {
        mCam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void initCamera() {
    mCamSV = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    mCamSH = mCamSV.getHolder();
    mCamSH.addCallback(this);
    mCamSH.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}


private void startCamera(SurfaceHolder sh, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters p = mCam.getParameters();
    // Camera.Size s = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
    p.setPreviewSize(width, height);

    mCam.setParameters(p);

    try {
        mCam.setPreviewDisplay(sh);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    mCam.startPreview();
}

private void stopCamera() {
    mCamSH.removeCallback(this);

    mCam.stopPreview();
    mCam.release();
}
```

}

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.stack.camera"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="CameraStackActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Check if it still doesnt work out for you.

Comment: This prevents force closing, but the camera never actually loads.

Comment: Hi i have edited my post with my files check if this works out for you. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your fixes. It removes the force close, but no preview appears on the screen. It could be that my phone only uses 2.1 and not 2.2. I'll investigate further. Thanks.